# web.xml Session timeout increment with IdleMonitor Tag

Tags: javascript, session, primefaces, web.xml

Hi I have session timeout 16 minutes in web.xml on the server side. and for front end we are using primefaces IdleMonitor tag to show warning message at 14.5 minutes.

User is getting into a screen where it shows huge search results, and user is just spending time to scroll through all the cases for 12 minutes, and then 4 minutes sitting idle,

to show the warning message Idle Monitor clock trigger at 12th minute because till 12th minute there was a mouse activity which server side session doesn't know, and after 16 minutes over if user clicks on some action its taking them to invalid session screen and re-login page,

User complains they are not receiving the warning, but the warning counter is not started until 12th minutes. so by the time background 16 minutes over Idle monitor clock just started 4 minutes ago so warning doesn't display.

How to sync IdleMonitor start clock to server side ?

I looked around stackoverflow and google here and there I could not find exact solution.

Looking for when IdleMonitor idle count starts counting thats where server session timeout start time also needs to start. both should be in sync. 
cannot extend session time due to security.

IdleMonitor tag posted in comment as description is not accepting the tag.

```
    <session-config>
    <session-timeout>16</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Comment: <p:idleMonitor onidle="PF('alertExpire').show();" timeout="870000" />

Comment: You can edit your question, it should normally accept the code

Comment: I try to edit, when I try to edit my code is already present but still not displayed so I just added idleMonitor tag in comment.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks